# Calling promise-driven functions regularly with setInterval and operating over its results

Tags: javascript

My goal is to make a video playlist generator that runs at specific times, along with a running clock and many other things that run periodically, but **I'm stuck at the part where it generates the playlist at the times I define**.

I'm using FileHound to walk a folder, which works whenever I call the `find()` method, but as it's Promise driven, its results aren't readily available to be used by the following `console.log()`, for example. Same thing happens with `MediaInfo()`, but this time I was able to work around it with `async/await`, which as far as I know is the actual way to use a Promise based function.

Now, as far as I can understand, the `.each()` and `.then()` method chaining are the ways to use the results from a Promise driven function, but that would quickly result in code repetition for every time I want to do the same thing in different places.

All being said, I think I'm off my track by very far, and despite my efforts I can't seem to find a clear way to achieve what I want, so I'm asking for help. This is the code I have so far, and I'm using the following `npm` packages:

- `node-mediainfo`
- `filehound`
- `moment`

```js
const MediaInfo = require("node-mediainfo");
const Path = require("path");
const FileHound = require("filehound");
const Moment = require("moment");

const START_TIME = Moment();
const END_TIME = null;
const VIDEO_PATH = "videos";

let files = FileHound.create()
  .path(VIDEO_PATH)
  .depth(0);
let playlist = [];
let start_time = START_TIME.add(10, "seconds");

const ArrayShuffle = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
};

const MakePlaylist = async (file) => {
  let fileinfo = await MediaInfo(Path.resolve(file));
  let duration = fileinfo.media.track[0].Duration;
  let title    = fileinfo.media.track[0].Title || Path.basename(file, Path.extname(file));
  let artist   = fileinfo.media.track[0].Performer || null;

  playlist.push({
    path    : Path.resolve(file),
    title   : title,
    artist  : artist,
    duration: duration
  });
};

console.log(start_time.toLocaleString());

/* Main Loop */
setInterval(() => {
  if (Moment().isSame(start_time)) {
    console.log("First Run");
    files.find().each(MakePlaylist).then(ArrayShuffle);
    console.log(playlist);
  }

  if (Moment().isSame(Moment(start_time).add(30, "seconds"))) {
    console.log("Second Run");
    playlist = [];
    files.find().each(MakePlaylist).then(ArrayShuffle);
    console.log(playlist);
  }
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to put your logic into an `async` function, making use of `await`. and then simply recall your function later, instead of trying to do it in `setTimeout`

Assuming `files.find()` returns a promise....

```
const GeneratePlaylist = async () => {
    var files = await files.find();
    var playlist = [];
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
       playlist.push(await MakePlaylist(files[i]));
    }
    ArrayShuffle(playlist);
    return playlist;
}
```

Then you can use that from another `async` function, and you can recall it 1ms later with `setTimeout` (Note, you should make `MakePlaylist` return the new item, not push to a global array):

```
const doMyThing = async (){
  if (Moment().isSame(start_time)) {
    console.log("First Run");
    playlist = await GeneratePlaylist();
    console.log(playlist);
  }

  if (Moment().isSame(Moment(start_time).add(30, "seconds"))) {
    console.log("Second Run");
    playlist = [];
    playlist = await GeneratePlaylist();
    console.log(playlist);
  }

  setTimeout(doMyThing,1);
}
```

Below is a working example, where I've just faked up some of your functionality using Promises to simulate asynchronous work like finding files and loading the media info:

```js
const ArrayShuffle = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
};

const MakePlaylist = async (file) => {
  let fileinfo = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({media:{track:[{Duration:1,Title:"Title",Performer:"Foo"}]}}),1000));
  let duration = fileinfo.media.track[0].Duration;
  let title    = fileinfo.media.track[0].Title || Path.basename(file, Path.extname(file));
  let artist   = fileinfo.media.track[0].Performer || null;

  return{
    path    : file,
    title   : title,
    artist  : artist,
    duration: duration
  };
};

const findFileMockup = () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"]);
   },500));
}

const GeneratePlaylist = async () => {
    var files = await findFileMockup(); // await files.find() in your code
    var playlist = [];
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
       playlist.push(await MakePlaylist(files[i]));
    }
    ArrayShuffle(playlist);
    return playlist;
}

const test = async () => {
  
    var playlist = await GeneratePlaylist();
    console.log(playlist);
  
}

test();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, implementing a `MainLoop()` as suggested in the second codeblock. The only thing that leaves me very puzzled is that when I run this code in the terminal runs fine, but when I run it in Visual Studio Code's debugger, it doesn't work as intended. Is it a runtime quirk?